# How to convert a 2D text file into a 2D array (Scala)

Tags: arrays, scala

How can I turn a text file into a 2D array in Scala? I'm reading in a text file name in the command line that then opens up the file within the program and the file contains 6 columns and a varying number of rows. I want to be able to turn that file into a 2D array so I can access the specific data. Each element in the file is separate by a space.

```
val filename = readLine()
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
  println(line)
}
val lines = io.Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.toArray
print(lines)
```

First two lines of the text file:

```
C#  CLA OLA Quiz Exam FinalExam
c1234501 10 20 10 30 30
```

So I want to skip that first line but put all those elements into an array. So array(0)(0) should contain 'c1234501' and array(0)(1) should contain '10'. I've never worked with Scala or Java before so I don't really know the syntax of the functions and nothing online is very helpful for this case.

Comment: @jwvh oh sorry. Each element is separated by a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the basic elements of file handling. You just need to `split()` each line of input text.

```
import scala.util.Try

val filename = ...
val file = Try(io.Source.fromFile(filename))                //open file
val data = file.map(_.getLines().map(_.split(" ")).toArray) //split each line
               .getOrElse(Array.empty[Array[String]])       //into an Array
file.fold(println, _.close())                   //close file or report error
```

To skip the 1st line of text add `.drop(1)` after the `.getLines()`.